# calculate difference between successive number and use to output to another dataframe in R

Tags: r, math, loops, dataset

I have following data set

```
mark <- c("0", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
phy <- c(0, 1, 10, 15, 18, 20)
gen <- c(0, 3, 35.0, 55, 60, 65)
mydata <- data.frame (mark, phy, gen)

  mark phy gen
1    0   0   0
2    A   1   3
3    B  10  35
4    C  15  55
5    D  18  60
6    E  20  65
```

I want substract the successive numbers in phy and gen (1 from 2, 2 from 3, and so on to end) and calculate the ratio, for example for the first case

```
(phy[2] - phy[1]) / (gen[2] - gen[1])
```

similarly for second case would be

```
(phy[3] - phy[2]) / (gen[3] - gen[2])
```

and so on ....

Thus output would be

```
phydis <- phy[i+1] - phy[i], where i is 1:6 (end of the data frame)

ratio <- (phy[i+1] - phy[i]) / (gen[i+1] - gen[i])
```

my manual calculations:

```
phydis <- c(1, 9, 5, 3, 2)
disg <- c(3, 32, 20, 5, 5)
ratio <- phydis / disg
 ratio
[1] 0.3333333 0.2812500 0.2500000 0.6000000 0.4000000
```

The ratio is conversion factor for the second data set. If anything between two phy value in above dataset will be multiplied by corresponding ratio.

My second data set:

```
mark <- c("i", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p")
phy <- c(3, 11, 12, 15, 17,18, 20)
mydf2 <- data.frame(mark, phy)
  mark phy
1    i   3
2    k  11
3    l  12
4    m  15
5    n  17
6    o  18
7    p  20
```

As mark i falls between mydata$phy 1-10, will be multiplied by ratio 0.2812500, similarly mark k phy value falls between  mydata$phy 10-15, will be multiplied by ratio 0.2500000. Thus complete math is

```
  mark phy  gen
1    i   3   3 * 0.2812500
2    k  11   11* 0.2500000
3    l  12   12 * 0.2500000
4    m  15   15 * 0.2500000
5    n  17   17 * 0.6000000
6    o  18   18 * 0.6000000
7    p  20   20 * 0.4000000
```

Unlike the dataset provided here, I have a big dataset to work on.

Edits:

Let me make clear about the second part:

based on first part we calculated ratio between intervals -

```
0 - 1,        1-10,      10-15,      15-18,    18-20 
0.3333333    0.2812500   0.2500000  0.6000000  0.4000000
```

Now the product factor will depend upon where mydf2$phy value fall in these intervals. For example first value mydf2$phy = 3, which falls between 1-10, thus will be multiplied by 0.2812500, The second value is 11 which falls between 10-15 thus will be multiplied by  0.2500000 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending Dason's answer:

```
mark <- c("0", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
phy <- c(0, 1, 10, 15, 18, 20)
gen <- c(0, 3, 35.0, 55, 60, 65)
mydata <- data.frame (mark, phy, gen)

ratio <- diff(mydata$phy)/diff(mydata$gen)

mark <- c("i", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p")
phy <- c(3, 11, 12, 15, 17,18, 20)
mydf2 <- data.frame(mark, phy)

mydf2$cat.phy <- cut(mydf2$phy, mydata$phy)
key <- data.frame(cat=levels(cut(mydf2$phy, mydata$phy)), ratio=ratio)
mydf2$gen <- mydf2$phy * key[match(mydf2$cat.phy, key$cat), 'ratio']

mydf2
```

Yielding:

```
> mydf2
  mark phy cat.phy      gen
1    i   3  (1,10]  0.84375
2    k  11 (10,15]  2.75000
3    l  12 (10,15]  3.00000
4    m  15 (10,15]  3.75000
5    n  17 (15,18] 10.20000
6    o  18 (15,18] 10.80000
7    p  20 (18,20]  8.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

This could take care of your first question:

```
# diff gives the successive differences
ratio <- diff(phy)/diff(gen)
```

and it's not clear to me how you're getting the numbers to multiply by for your second questions.